# jQuery: Compact way to fetch values of all input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with five input fields and a register button ('.register').

I want to enable the register button ONLY IF all fields have at least one character.

Here comes my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // when page loads
    $('.register').addClass('a_unclickable');

    // Input validation
    // Are all fields filled out?
    $('input').on('keyup', function() {

        var un_value = $('#username_operators').val();
        var fn_value = $('#first_name_operators').val();
        var ln_value = $('#last_name_operators').val();
        var e_value = $('#email_operators').val();
        var pw_value = $('#password_operators').val();
        var pw_r_value = $('#password_repeat_operators').val();

        if ((un_value.length > 0) && (fn_value.length > 0) && (ln_value.length > 0) && (e_value.length > 0) && (e_value.indexOf('@') !== -1) && (pw_value.length > 0) && (pw_r_value.length > 0)) {
            $('.register').removeClass('a_unclickable');
        } else {
            $('.register').addClass('a_unclickable');
        }

    })

});
```

I have the feeling that there is a much easier way to achieve the same result. Does anyone of you have a compact suggestion?

Comment: Can you post the HTML for reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quiet compact:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // when page loads
    $('.register').addClass('a_unclickable');

    // Input validation
    // Are all fields filled out?
    $('input').on('keyup', function() {
        $('.register').removeClass('a_unclickable');

        $('input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === '') {
                $('.register').addClass('a_unclickable');
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56yYj/)

```
var arr = [un_value, fn_value, ln_value, e_value, pw_value, pw_r_value];

$.each(arr,function(i,item){ if(item.length > 0){
      $('.register').removeClass('a_unclickable');
    } else {
        $('.register').addClass('a_unclickable');
    }})
```

if you are able to read all the values with selector you could pass them 
like:

```
 $.each($('input'),function(i,item){ if($(item).val().length > 0){
      $('.register').removeClass('a_unclickable');
    } else {
        $('.register').addClass('a_unclickable');
    }})
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind. First:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    var valid = true;

    $('#username_operators, #first_name_operators, #last_name_operators, #email_operators, #password_operators, #password_repeat_operators').each(function() {
        if (/^\s*$/.test(this.value)) {
            valid = false;
        }
    });

    if (valid) {
        $('.register').removeClass('a_unclickable');
    }
    else {
        $('.register').addClass('a_unclickable');
    }
});
```

You can combine all the Ids into one CSS selector. Really the cleanest way is to add a class name to each required input, then utilize `event.target.form` to find all required fields inside the form.

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(event) {
    var valid = true;

    $(event.target.form).find(".required").each(function() {
        if (/^\s*$/.test(this.value)) {
            valid = false;
        }
    });

    if (valid) {
        $('.register').removeClass('a_unclickable');
    }
    else {
        $('.register').addClass('a_unclickable');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the inputs in a `<div class="verifyLength" ></div>`
Add the a_unclickable class to the register field by default.

Then jquery:

```
 $('input').on('keyup', function() {
    var emptyField = false;
    $(".verfyLength").find("input").each(function()
    {
      if((this).val().length() <=0)
       emptyField = true;
    });
    if(emptyField)
        $('.register').addClass('a_unclickable');       
    else
        $('.register').removeClass('a_unclickable');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mR5jw/):

```
var i = 0, count = 0;
$.each($( ":input" ), function( index, value ) {
    if(value.value.length > 0) {
        count++;
    }
});

if(count === 6) {
    console.log(true);   
} else {
    console.log(false)
}
```

Comment: Hmmmmm... I don't like the magic bullet number of 6 in there. Shouldn't you replace that with something that actually counted the number of inputs?

Comment: Splitting hairs. Just showing some king of flag for an example.